# Update take too long

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having a table with around 60000 rows. I am using MS SQL Server Express 2012.

When updating, it takes long time to finish.

My table design is as below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Entry_Jangad_Lot](
[Srno] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Kapan] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Lotno] [int] NOT NULL,
[Quality] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Pcs] [int] NOT NULL,
[Caret] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[JangadNo] [int] NOT NULL,
[IssuedTo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[IssuedDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ReceivedPcs] [int] NULL,
[ReceivedCaret] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[ReceivedDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ReceivedType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Position] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Process] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[MergedStatus] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[MergedToLotno] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Entry_Jangad_Lot_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Srno] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =   OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am using following Procedure to update a table record.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_add_update_lot_receive]
(
@mode nvarchar(50),
@Kapan nvarchar(50),
@Lotno int,
@ReceivedPcs int,
@ReceivedCaret decimal(18,2),
@ReceivedDate nvarchar(50),
@ReceivedType nvarchar(50)
)
as
if @mode='ADD'
begin
    declare @srno int
    select @srno=srno from Entry_Jangad_Lot where Kapan=@Kapan
    and Lotno=@Lotno
    and Position='CURRENT'

    update Entry_Jangad_Lot set
    ReceivedPcs=@ReceivedPcs,
    ReceivedCaret=@ReceivedCaret,
    ReceivedDate=@ReceivedDate,
    ReceivedType=@ReceivedType,
    Status='RECEIVED'
    where srno=@srno
    --where Kapan=@Kapan
    --and Lotno=@Lotno
    --and Position='CURRENT'

    if @ReceivedType='POLISH'
    begin
        update Entry_Jangad_Lot set
        Process='POLISH'
        where srno=@srno
        --where Kapan=@Kapan
        --and Lotno=@Lotno
        --and Position='CURRENT'

    end
    else
    begin
        if @ReceivedType='TABLE'
        begin
            update Entry_Jangad_Lot set
            Process='TABLE'
            where srno=@srno
            --where Kapan=@Kapan
            --and Lotno=@Lotno
            --and Position='CURRENT'
        end
        else
        begin
            update Entry_Jangad_Lot set
            Process='NOTPOLISH'
            where srno=@srno
            --where Kapan=@Kapan
            --and Lotno=@Lotno
            --and Position='CURRENT'
        end

    end
end
GO
```

Following indexes are also available.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Entry_Jangad_Lot] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Entry_Jangad_Lot_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Srno] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20150422-160201] ON [dbo].[Entry_Jangad_Lot]
(
    [Kapan] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20150422-155655] ON [dbo].[Entry_Jangad_Lot]
(
    [Kapan] ASC,
    [Lotno] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**EDIT**

```
    /****** Object:  Statistic [_WA_Sys_00000003_47DBAE45]    Script Date: 27/04/2015 12:33:24 ******/
CREATE STATISTICS [_WA_Sys_00000003_47DBAE45] ON [dbo].[Entry_Jangad_Lot]([Lotno]) WITH STATS_STREAM = 0x01000000010000000000000000000000B90F1C72000000000B19000000000000CB18000000000000380374003800000004000A00000000000000000042004300070000002508C40085A400004ECE000000000000ADA80000000000005DCA253D8A4B863B0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000C1000000C1000000010000001400000000008040004E4E4700000000000080400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000000000000000000000000000005F17000000000000671700000000000008060000000000001F0600000000000036060000000000004D0600000000000064060000000000007B060000000000009206000000000000A906000000000000C006000000000000D706000000000000EE0600000000000005070000000000001C0700000000000033070000000000004A07000000000000610700000000000078070000000000008F07000000000000A607000000000000BD07000000000000D407000000000000EB0700000000000002080000000000001908000000000000300800000000000047080000000000005E0800000000000075080000000000008C08000000000000A308000000000000BA08000000000000D108000000000000E808000000000000FF0800000000000016090000000000002D0900000000000044090000000000005B0900000000000072090000000000008909000000000000A009000000000000B709000000000000CE09000000000000E509000000000000FC09000000000000130A0000000000002A0A000000000000410A000000000000580A0000000000006F0A000000000000860A0000000000009D0A000000000000B40A000000000000CB0A000000000000E20A000000000000F90A000000000000100B000000000000270B0000000000003E0B000000000000550B0000000000006C0B000000000000830B0000000000009A0B000000000000B10B000000000000C80B000000000000DF0B000000000000F60B0000000000000D0C000000000000240C0000000000003B0C000000000000520C000000000000690C000000000000800C000000000000970C000000000000AE0C000000000000C50C000000000000DC0C000000000000F30C0000000000000A0D000000000000210D000000000000380D0000000000004F0D000000000000660D0000000000007D0D000000000000940D000000000000AB0D000000000000C20D000000000000D90D000000000000F00D000000000000070E0000000000001E0E000000000000350E0000000000004C0E000000000000630E0000000000007A0E000000000000910E000000000000A80E000000000000BF0E000000000000D60E000000000000ED0E000000000000040F0000000000001B0F000000000000320F000000000000490F000000000000600F000000000000770F0000000000008E0F000000000000A50F000000000000BC0F000000000000D30F000000000000EA0F000000000000011000000000000018100000000000002F1000000000000046100000000000005D1000000000000074100000000000008B10000000000000A210000000000000B910000000000000D010000000000000E710000000000000FE1000000000000015110000000000002C1100000000000043110000000000005A11000000000000711100000000000088110000000000009F11000000000000B611000000000000CD11000000000000E411000000000000FB1100000000000012120000000000002912000000000000401200000000000057120000000000006E1200000000000085120000000000009C12000000000000B312000000000000CA12000000000000E112000000000000F8120000000000000F1300000000000026130000000000003D1300000000000054130000000000006B1300000000000082130000000000009913000000000000B013000000000000C713000000000000DE13000000000000F5130000000000000C1400000000000023140000000000003A14000000000000511400000000000068140000000000007F140000000000009614000000000000AD14000000000000C414000000000000DB14000000000000F2140000000000000915000000000000201500000000000037150000000000004E1500000000000065150000000000007C150000000000009315000000000000AA15000000000000C115000000000000D815000000000000EF1500000000000006160000000000001D1600000000000034160000000000004B16000000000000621600000000000079160000000000009016000000000000A716000000000000BE16000000000000D516000000000000EC1600000000000003170000000000001A1700000000000031170000000000004817000000000000100014005CD2ED43000000000000803F01000000040000100014004036ED43000000000000803F02000000040000100014006255E843000000000000803F03000000040000100014004036ED43000000000000803F0400000004000010001400786EEE43000000000000803F05000000040000100014006255E843000000000000803F0600000004000010001400D1C5EA43000000000000803F0700000004000010001400AFA6EF43000000000000803F0800000004000010001400B529EA43000000000000803F0900000004000010001400C5BFF543000000000000803F0A00000004000010001400AA23F543000000000000803F0B00000004000010001400E7DEF043000000000000803F0C0000000400001000140008FEEB43000000000000803F0D0000000400001000140046B9E743000000000000803F0E0000000400001000140046B9E743000000000000803F0F00000004000010001400D1C5EA43000000000000803F10000000040000100014000E81E643000000000000803F11000000040000100014000E81E643000000000000803F1200000004000010001400ED61EB43000000000000803F1300000004000010001400D748E543000000000000803F14000000040000100014001404E143000000000000803F15000000040000100014003623DC43000000000000803F1600000004000010001400FEEADA43000000000000803F1700000004000010001400DCCBDF43000000000000803F18000000040000100014004C3CE243000000000000803F19000000040000100014004C3CE243000000000000803F1A00000004000010001400A593DE43000000000000803F1B00000004000010001400F867E043000000000000803F1C0000000400001000140073DED743000000000000803F1D00000004000010001400C12FDF43000000000000803F1E00000004000010001400E24EDA43000000000000803F1F00000004000010001400FEEADA43000000000000803F2000000004000010001400F2E4E543000000000000803F21000000040000100014001A87DB43000000000000803F22000000040000100014003BA6D643000000000000803F2300000004000010001400E8D1D443000000000000803F2400000004000010001400046ED543000000000000803F2500000004000010001400CC35D443000000000000803F260000000400001000140094FDD243000000000000803F27000000040000100014007961D243000000000000803F28000000040000100014005DC5D143000000000000803F29000000040000100014009A80CD43000000000000803F2A00000004000010001400B099D343000000000000803F2B0000000400001000140094FDD243000000000000803F2C00000004000010001400D2B8CE43000000000000803F2D00000004000010001400258DD043000000000000803F2E000000040000100014007EE4CC43000000000000803F2F000000040000100014002B10CB43000000000000803F3000000004000010001400258DD043000000000000803F31000000040000100014006E4EC143000000000000803F320000000400001000140015F7C443000000000000803F3300000004000010001400B61CCE43000000000000803F3400000004000010001400DDBEC343000000000000803F3500000004000010001400C7A5BD43000000000000803F3600000004000010001400E341BE43000000000000803F3700000004000010001400A686C243000000000000803F3800000004000010001400FFDDBE43000000000000803F3900000004000010001400906DBC43000000000000803F3A000000040000100014001B7ABF43000000000000803F3B00000004000010001400E341BE43000000000000803F3C00000004000010001400B18CB743000000000000803F3D00000004000010001400E9C4B843000000000000803F3E000000040000100014007FD7B043000000000000803F3F0000000400001000140095F0B643000000000000803F40000000040000100014000AE4B343000000000000803F4100000004000010001400EF47B343000000000000803F4200000004000010001400421CB543000000000000803F4300000004000010001400643BB043000000000000803F4400000004000010001400643BB043000000000000803F4500000004000010001400F4CAAD43000000000000803F460000000400001000140016EAA843000000000000803F47000000040000100014002680B443000000000000803F48000000040000100014003286A943000000000000803F490000000400001000140069BEAA43000000000000803F4A000000040000100014004E22AA43000000000000803F4B000000040000100014004E22AA43000000000000803F4C0000000400001000140000D1A243000000000000803F4D0000000400001000140053A5A443000000000000803F4E000000040000100014000BD79743000000000000803F4F000000040000100014000BD79743000000000000803F5000000004000010001400430F9943000000000000803F510000000400001000140006549D43000000000000803F5200000004000010001400CE1B9C43000000000000803F530000000400001000140080CA9443000000000000803F5400000004000010001400B8029643000000000000803F550000000400001000140080CA9443000000000000803F56000000040000100014009C669543000000000000803F5700000004000010001400BE859043000000000000803F580000000400001000140033798D43000000000000803F59000000040000100014006AB18E43000000000000803F5A00000004000010001400864D8F43000000000000803F5B00000004000010001400A86C8A43000000000000803F5C00000004000010001400E5278643000000000000803F5D0000000400001000140017DD8C43000000000000803F5E00000004000010001400E5278643000000000000803F5F0000000400001000140038FC8743000000000000803F6000000004000010001400DFA48B43000000000000803F610000000400001000140054988843000000000000803F6200000004000010001400ADEF8443000000000000803F63000000040000100014003E7F8243000000000000803F6400000004000010001400CF0E8043000000000000803F650000000400001000140022E38143000000000000803F6600000004000010001400C03C7B43000000000000803F6700000004000010001400AA237543000000000000803F6800000004000010001400037B7143000000000000803F69000000040000100014007DF16843000000000000803F6A00000004000010001400249A6C43000000000000803F6B00000004000010001400249A6C43000000000000803F6C0000000400001000140046B96743000000000000803F6D00000004000010001400ED616B43000000000000803F6E00000004000010001400249A6C43000000000000803F6F00000004000010001400249A6C43000000000000803F7000000004000010001400D7486543000000000000803F710000000400001000140030A06143000000000000803F720000000400001000140051BF5C43000000000000803F730000000400001000140073DE5743000000000000803F7400000004000010001400CC355443000000000000803F75000000040000100014007EE44C43000000000000803F760000000400001000140068CB4643000000000000803F770000000400001000140068CB4643000000000000803F780000000400001000140068CB4643000000000000803F79000000040000100014007EE44C43000000000000803F7A00000004000010001400A0034843000000000000803F7B000000040000100014005EB83543000000000000803F7C0000000400001000140052B24043000000000000803F7D000000040000100014008AEA4143000000000000803F7E0000000400001000140095F03643000000000000803F7F00000004000010001400EF473343000000000000803F8000000004000010001400E3413E43000000000000803F8100000004000010001400CD283843000000000000803F82000000040000100014005EB83543000000000000803F8300000004000010001400489F2F43000000000000803F840000000400001000140005613943000000000000803F8500000004000010001400D92E2D43000000000000803F860000000400001000140010672E43000000000000803F8700000004000010001400B70F3243000000000000803F8800000004000010001400A1F62B43000000000000803F8900000004000010001400EF473343000000000000803F8A000000040000100014005EB83543000000000000803F8B000000040000100014007FD73043000000000000803F8C0000000400001000140010672E43000000000000803F8D00000004000010001400D92E2D43000000000000803F8E00000004000010001400ACFC2043000000000000803F8F0000000400001000140075C41F43000000000000803F9000000004000010001400ACFC2043000000000000803F9100000004000010001400CE1B1C43000000000000803F92000000040000100014008BDD2543000000000000803F9300000004000010001400CE1B1C43000000000000803F9400000004000010001400C3080B43CA0F1A43CA0F1A43960000000400001000140080CA1443000000000000803F9700000004000010001400E52706433EAA0C433EAA0C43990000000400001000140067D8E2429BF201439BF201439B000000040000100014001A87DB42000000000000803F9C00000004000010001400EE54CF42000000000000803F9D0000000400001000140089F7DD42000000000000803F9E00000004000010001400A003C8427B62DE427B62DE42A00000000400001000140052B2C0427B62DE427B62DE42A200000004000010001400D92EAD42A88DBB42A88DBB42A400000004000010001400489FAF42000000000000803FA500000004000010001400CE1B9C42EE83B342EE83B342A7000000040000100014008BDDA542000000000000803FA8000000040000100014005FAB9942000000000000803FA900000004000010001400A2E98F42000000000000803FAA000000040000100014005FAB9942000000000000803FAB0000000400001000140076B78342000000000000803FAC00000004000010001400115A9242000000000000803FAD0000000400001000140033798D42ED0A9642ED0A9642AF0000000400001000140076B78342000000000000803FB000000004000010001400F03A974290C2A04290C2A042B2000000040000100014001A875B427BDB7B427BDB7B42B400000004000010001400D7486542000000000000803FB500000004000010001400F867604207C86B4207C86B42B7000000040000100014003BA65642000000000000803FB80000000400001000140069BE2A42000000000000803FB900000004000010001400056139421DA14B421DA14B42BB00000004000010001400A0034842000000000000803FBC000000040000100014008BDD2542A88D3B42A88D3B42BE0000000400001000140033790D42BE669B42BE661B42C10000000400001000140033790D42621E2642621E2642C3000000040000100014002FADFD41000000000000803FC40000000400001000140076B70342BE661B42BE661B42C600000004000010001400F867E041000000000000803FC7000000040000100014002FADFD41000000000000803FC8000000040000100014000561B941000000000000803FC9000000040000100014000561B941AA7F7642AA7FF641CC000000040000100014007EE4CC41000000000000803FCD000000040000100014008BDDA541ED0A9642910EC841D100000004000010001400C2224341BE661B42BE669B41D400000004000010001400489F2F4107C8EB4107C86B41D7000000040000100014007D6E9940AA7F76421C552441DE000000040000100014003505C240000000000000803FDF0000000400001000140038720040356C6642480A4240F3000000040000100014000000803F000000000000803FF40000000400004ECE000000000000
GO
/****** Object:  Statistic [_WA_Sys_0000000A_47DBAE45]    Script Date: 27/04/2015 12:33:24 ******/
CREATE STATISTICS [_WA_Sys_0000000A_47DBAE45] ON [dbo].[Entry_Jangad_Lot]([Status]) WITH STATS_STREAM = 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
GO
/****** Object:  Statistic [_WA_Sys_0000000E_47DBAE45]    Script Date: 27/04/2015 12:33:24 ******/
CREATE STATISTICS [_WA_Sys_0000000E_47DBAE45] ON [dbo].[Entry_Jangad_Lot]([ReceivedType]) WITH STATS_STREAM = 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
GO
/****** Object:  Statistic [_WA_Sys_0000000F_47DBAE45]    Script Date: 27/04/2015 12:33:24 ******/
CREATE STATISTICS [_WA_Sys_0000000F_47DBAE45] ON [dbo].[Entry_Jangad_Lot]([Position]) WITH STATS_STREAM = 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
GO
/****** Object:  Statistic [_WA_Sys_00000010_47DBAE45]    Script Date: 27/04/2015 12:33:24 ******/
CREATE STATISTICS [_WA_Sys_00000010_47DBAE45] ON [dbo].[Entry_Jangad_Lot]([Process]) WITH STATS_STREAM = 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
GO
```

**EDIT**

> DECLARE   @return_value int
>
> EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[sp_add_update_lot_receive]       @mode =
>   N'ADD',       @Kapan = N'299/SL',         @Lotno = 164,       @ReceivedPcs = 300,
>         @ReceivedCaret = 2.90,      @ReceivedDate = N'27/04/2015',
>         @ReceivedType = N'POLISH'
>
> SELECT    'Return Value' = @return_value
>
> GO

Comment: What are the available indexes on your table?

Comment: Just added it with an edit. Please have a look.

Comment: can you share stats using it

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/05/sql-server-copy-statistics-from-one-server-to-another-server/

MIGHT be parameter sniffing

Comment: Trying to add statistics but Its too long and it cant be inserted here.

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma, Due to body characters limit here, Only adding what I could in the EDIT section.

Comment: your input as well into sp please

Comment: Added a working Stored Procedure with sample data in latest EDIT. @NeerajPrasadSharma

Comment: Mate i can`t see statistics on the keys

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your logic, doesn't this do the trick much more simply:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_add_update_lot_receive]
(
@mode nvarchar(50),
@Kapan nvarchar(50),
@Lotno int,
@ReceivedPcs int,
@ReceivedCaret decimal(18,2),
@ReceivedDate nvarchar(50),
@ReceivedType nvarchar(50)
)
as
if @mode='ADD'
begin

    update Entry_Jangad_Lot set
    ReceivedPcs=@ReceivedPcs,
    ReceivedCaret=@ReceivedCaret,
    ReceivedDate=@ReceivedDate,
    ReceivedType=@ReceivedType,
    Status='RECEIVED',

    Process = coalesce (t.Process, 'NOTPOLISH')

    from Entry_Jangad_Lot
    outer apply (values
        ('TABLE'),
        ('POLISH')
    ) t(Process)

    where Kapan=@Kapan
      and Lotno=@Lotno
      and Position='CURRENT'

      and t.Process = Entry_Jangad_Lot.Process
end
```

Comment: This one not as per my logic. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look too bad.  If I had to guess (and I do because I am not near SQL Server Express) I'd say it's because you've got an INT srno converted to a BIGINT version on the index.  That could be resulting in an implicit conversion that stops the index being used.

Also, you have an unneeded index (the one with Kapan and Lotno will serve as just Kapan too).

Also, define "long time" :)